# Can I update Minecraft and not lose modded items and progress?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I don't mean asking about changing the version of old mods to newer, I just want to update my official Minecraft version from 1.12.2 to the newest one (1.13 or 1.14, for example). But I have 15 mods installed (furniture mods included) on 1.12.2 and have already built a giant house using all that stuff the furniture mod gives me. I won't be playing the game again if EACH and EVERY stuff from mods in my house will be deleted with an update (my house is like 75% built of stuff from mods).

Is it possible to install all the same version mods on the newer version, join my world and find everything in place? Or even if I will install all the same mods (when they come out on the recent versions, of course) on 1.13 or 1.14, all my modded stuff will be "vanished" from the old world anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to update both the mods you're using and update the core game itself before loading your world. It also never hurts to make a backup of your world.

Once you update your mods to support 1.13 and update the game itself, load a new world to make sure you still have access to your modded blocks. If you do, fire up your previous world (that you should have backed up) and you should be good.

If things go awry, you can downgrade back to 1.12 and use your backed up world.